# Getting null in some columns in hive due to next line "\n" within records

Tags: hive

I have a table where I have next line character ("\n") within my records. So when I  do select * on table, I get null values in the column which come after the records with "\n" or sometimes I get multiple records for a single record.
I get above problem in terminal,DB Visualizer and Tableau everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored correctly but this error is because hive is not able to provide in proper format. So we need to change the query output format of hive. We need to set below property :

```
set hive.query.result.fileformat=SequenceFile;
```

Its default value was TextFile which was giving an error.

Default Value:
Hive 0.x, 1.x, and 2.0: TextFile
Hive 2.1 onward: SequenceFile

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties